# how to search for pattern in file and display the line on terminal?

Tags: linux, grep

i have filw with containtent like following:

```
pid 4565 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +34787[d]sfh888dwe4rtertfsj@##$
pid 33453 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$
pid 3453345 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +3478[7]dsfhew46534wy6888dfsj@##$
pid 12335 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +3478se[r]tet57dsfh888dfsj@##$
```

i need line contaning "+34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$" this pattern and need to get whole that line on terminal or can ne redirected to another file. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man grep`? could that work for ya'?

Comment: @ALL Thanks for the support, I got the required output with the use of -a option, Because my file was binary file so to search pattern we need -a option as follows: grep -a "my_pattern" file.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep with fixed strings mode (aka fgrep):

```
grep -F '+34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$' /path/to/my/file
```

Run `man grep` to learn  more.

If you need to redirect it to some output file instead of standards output:

```
grep -F '+34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$' /path/to/my/file > /path/to/my/output
```

Run `man sh` or `man bash` and read about Redirections.

Answer (score 0):

grep/awk/sed... many tools can do that. grep example:

```
 kent$  echo "pid 4565 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +34787[d]sfh888dwe4rtertfsj@##$
    pid 33453 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$
    pid 3453345 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +3478[7]dsfhew46534wy6888dfsj@##$
    pid 12335 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +3478se[r]tet57dsfh888dfsj@##$"|grep '\+34787\[d\]sfh888dfsj@##werwer\$'

    pid 33453 Process: /my/name/is/4678 +34787[d]sfh888dfsj@##werwer$
```